# chmod apply to user group

Tags: ubuntu, chmod, groups

I need to set the permissions of a dir so that a usergroup in my ubuntu-server has read/write permissions. I understand that I'm supposed to use chmod (right?), but how do I set the permissions to only apply to a single usergroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chgrp $GROUPNAME $DIRNAME
chown g=$PERMS
```

Where $DIRNAME is the directory you want to change, $GROUPNAME is the name of the group you want the directory to be owned by, and $PERMS is the combination of `rwx` that you want to change permissions to.

Comment: what is "g" in the second row?

Comment: @mr.axelander: Group. That only modifies the group level permissions, leaving the user and world permissions unchanged.

Comment: sry, but i dont understand. Say i want to change the permissions for the dir x to 777 for the group y. What would i then write ?

Comment: @mr.axelander: You don't. When dealing with permissions in octal, 7 indicates "read/write/execute". Then using `777` what you're saying is, "Give read/write/execute permissions to the user-owner/group-owner/everyone on the file." While technically using '777' will give the group rwx permissions, it also gives *everyone* rwx rights.

Comment: @mr.axelander I think you have not understood permisions fully. 777 means all persimisions to all. in this first 7 is for owner of the file. 2nd 7 is for group which file owner is a member of other and thrid 7 is for all others. If you want to change permission for a single group , make the dir part of that group and do chmod g+rw <dir> and make sure you have permission to do so in that dir.

Comment: @ashwin - the file owner is not necessarily a member of the group associated with the file.  Of course, from a permissions evaluation standpoint, that doesn't matter, since matching the userid associated with the file means the group and other permissions won't be evaluated.